# Spring DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm making a spring mvc project and i'm stuck in the following error.
I have a java based configuration with 3 files

AppConfig java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.gmc.controller")
@Import(DBConfig.class)
@EnableWebMvc   
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {   
    @Bean  
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {  
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;  
    }
    @Bean 
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/i18/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("mylocale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }  
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app-resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }    
}
```

WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

DBConfig

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class DBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
    }
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        lsfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lsfb.setPackagesToScan("com.gmc.entity");
        lsfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        try {
            lsfb.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lsfb.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        try {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.root"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibTransMan(){
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I have a database.properties with my database details
I'm using Intellij Idea, and i have a connection enabled to my remote host, i can create a hibernate.cfg.xml with all my tables.
**My connection is a remote db, not local**

```
database.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:620xx/xxxxx
database.root = ebspma_gesdocent
database.password =xxxxxx
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

When i run the project i have the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, this problem is connection problem or config problem??
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
From the debug, reaching the return dataSource in DBConfig

```
    defaultAutoCommit = null
defaultReadOnly = null
defaultTransactionIsolation = -1
defaultQueryTimeout = null
defaultCatalog = null
cacheState = true
driver = null
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
driverClassLoader = null
lifo = true
maxTotal = 8
maxIdle = 8
minIdle = 0
initialSize = 0
maxWaitMillis = -1
poolPreparedStatements = false
maxOpenPreparedStatements = -1
testOnCreate = false
testOnBorrow = true
testOnReturn = false
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = -1
numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis = -1
evictionPolicyClassName = "org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy"
testWhileIdle = false
password = "1-RCqITS=.9B"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:xxxx/xxxx"
username = "ebspma_gesdocent"
validationQuery = null
validationQueryTimeout = -1
connectionInitSqls = null
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed = false
maxConnLifetimeMillis = -1
logExpiredConnections = true
jmxName = null
enableAutoCommitOnReturn = true
rollbackOnReturn = true
disconnectionSqlCodes = null
fastFailValidation = false
connectionPool = null
connectionProperties = {Properties@4254}  size = 0
dataSource = null
logWriter = {PrintWriter@4255} 
abandonedConfig = null
closed = false
registeredJmxName = null
```

By this, it is clear that the application.properties is read, but i dont have the following details

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

I'm lost...

Comment: it looks like your code is nor reading properly your hibernate.dialect property, did you debug and checked it ?

Comment: check my update please